# Visual Studio 2010 debugging options missing from toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I haven't had much luck in finding an answer to this, I just switched computers and during debugging I noticed that only 'Step over' appears on the toolbar, there is no 'Step Into' or 'Step out'. Following some advice online I attempted going to Tools ->Customize ->Commands. I confirmed that the buttons are present under the 'Debug' menu bar (Although if I actually go to that Menu I once again only see 'Step over'). Some answers for Visual Studio 2008 said that its possible to drag and drop the commands, I haven't been able to do this either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

if you right-click on the toolbar and select the option at the bottom which is "customize..."

then go to commands and select the radiobutton for toolbar.

go to the the item "debug" and click the button "Add command"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by going to Tools -> Import and Export Settings Wizard -> Reset all settings. Then just going through the wizard.